# jQuery Datatable ajax json request

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to fill my datatable using their own api, and well it doesn't even send the request...

Here is my code...

```
$('#dataTableJson').dataTable( {
    "bProcessing": false,
    "sAjaxSource" : "http://localhost/Manage/Resident/Liste/json"
});
```

and here is the firebug list of net request...

http://www.softwareishard.com/har/viewer/?inputUrl=http://dl.dropbox.com/u/41952627/localhost.harp

Any idea what is wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to retrieve data from any server or domain you must change to jsonp:

http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/jsonp.html

But if you want retrieve data from a page in your site:

```
$('#dataTableJson').dataTable( {
"bProcessing": false,
"sAjaxSource" : "MyJsonHandler.php"
});
```